# NestJS: Injected dependencies are undefined during cron job execution

Tags: nestjs

I cannot get the contextual reference of the `MyOtherService`.

Following the [docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/task-scheduling), this is my code:

```
@Injectable()
export class MyService {
    constructor(private readonly myOtherService: MyOtherService) {}

    @Cron(CronExpression.EVERY_10_SECONDS)
    async test() {
        this.myOtherService.someMethod()  //myOtherService is undefined;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is `MyOtherService` `REQUET` scoped? Or are any of it's dependencies?

Comment: DEFAULT scoped...

Comment: And the service has dependencies on typeORM repositories

Comment: Turns out there was a request scoped dependency, if you want to create an answer I will gladly accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you have a dependency using the `REQUEST` scope, which cannot be instantiated during CRON as there is no request to work with. Everything must be the singleton (DEFAULT) scope.